# DITA XML: How can I add a link to the table of contents?

Tags: xml, dita, tableofcontents

How can I add a link inside a DITA topic which directs to the complete document's table of contents?

The table is automatically generated and I can't figure out how to attach a key to it.

Comment: Do you mean, the table of contents in the map generated thanks to the `<toc>` element?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add an `id` attribute to the `<toc>` element and then in your topic content use a `<link>` or  `<xref>` to point to that. For example:

your-map.ditamap

`...
<toc id="toc"/>
...`

your-topic.dita

`...
<xref href="your-map.ditamap#toc"/>
...`

The thing is, your DITA processor might not support this; also, you can't use this approach if you're not using Bookmap, since normal map doesn't have a `<toc>` element.

Answer (score 2):

The DITA markup does not have any element for this. A TOC is a generated artifact that is generated for some -- not all -- rendered collections of DITA content. A DITA topic has no "knowledge" of its larger context, and so there is no way to add markup to a topic that links to a TOC.

Comment: I was trying to answer the question and I find out that the `<toc>` is allowed to bear a `keys` attribute. Thus I imagine that it would be possible to declare `<toc keys="toc"/>` in the bookmap and insert a `<xref keyref="toc"/>` -- even if looks senseless for me.